# How to do combineLatest operator in valueChanges subscriptions

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs6

```
showDateCriteria = combineLatest(this.myForm.controls['name'].valueChanges, this.myForm.controls['age'].valueChanges, (name, age) => ({name, age}))
.subscribe(val => !(val.name==null ||val.age==null ));
```

I have tried this code with **combineLatest** Operator and **showDateCriteria**

```
<div *ngIf="{{showDateCriteria | async}}">Show This</div>
```

I am unable to show the `<div>` eventhough particular condition is satisfied

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rs3d7a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`.

You're trying to async pipe a subscription, which doesn't make sense.

You should pipe streams.

```
this.showDateCriteria =
    combineLatest(
        this.myForm.controls['name'].valueChanges,
        this.myForm.controls['age'].valueChanges, (name, age) => ({
            name,
            age
        }));
this.showDateCriteria.subscribe(val => !(val.name == null || val.age == null));
```

EDIT:

You should also `startWith`, otherwise the `combineLatest` will not trigger.
Also, the logic was wrong, you should return `boolean` `true` when either of them is not null, like so:

```
this.showDateCriteria = combineLatest(
    this.myForm.controls['name'].valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),
    this.myForm.controls['age'].valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),
    (name, age) => {
        console.log(name);
        return name || age;
    });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6vi6k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks but what should be the type of showDateCriteria ??

Comment: Observable. Read the documentation. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: i have updated my stackblitz could you please verify the output https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rs3d7a

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @ritraj, one ,more thing can i specify type of showDateCriteria as Observable<boolean> ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you should type it!